# Error when loading a C++ statc library in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab

I've built a static library from a C++ code using CodeBlocks with mingw32. I have 64 bit Windows and MATLAB. When I try to load this library into MATLAB using `loadlibrary` it gives the following error:

```
 statlib.a is not a valid win32 application
```

As I said, I compiled this library using mingw32. What can I do now?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? How are you *loading* the library into MATLAB, and assuming you were successful in doing so, what would you want to have happen next?

Comment: @Praetorian Using `loadlibrary`.

Comment: [Here's the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html) for `loadlibrary`. It only works with shared libraries, not static libraries. The latter must be linked to an executable, either directly or indirectly. You cannot use them standalone.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be building a Dynamic Link Library?  The extension to most Window's dynamic link libraries is `.DLL`, not `.a`.  The `.a` sounds like you built a `static library`, not a DLL.